# Choice pattern in properties file

Tags: java, properties, message

I have a properties file with messages and I want to handle some special cases of plural. Now I use:

```
xxx.yyy.plural=test{0,choice,2#y}
```

but it formats 12 as 'testy' also. How can I specify 2 as exact match?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html (not an answer)

Comment: The link above doesn't address the issue. The following one seems closer to me: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an answer. It seems that choice statement in properties file works properly only if more than one choice is specified. So you have to specify at least one "else branch" 
If i rewrite my example:

```
xxx.yyy.plural={0,choice,2#testy|2<test}
```