# Message format choice in properties file

Tags: java, properties, messageformat

I have looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138279/choice-pattern-in-properties-file), and can't see what I am doing wrong. I am using MessageFormat to get a property from a file, and want to make the property dynamic depending on whether the integer passed in is 1 or higher. The property in the file looks like this:

```
Prop1=Invalid password entered. You have {0,number,integer} {0,choice,1#attempt|1<attempts} remaining.
```

In the code, I read this property in, and then pass an array of arguments to `MessageFormat.format()` (I pass an array for consistency across all properties. In this case, the only object present is the string representation of an integer value)
Whilst debugging the code, I can see that this string gets read, but `MessageFormat.format()` doesn't seem to format the string as expected. The result looks like this:

```
"Invalid password entered. You have {0,number,integer} {0,choice, 1#attempt|1<attempts} remaining."
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? As I stated earlier, I am passing in the string representation of the integer value, but I assumed that the code above would be able to handle it. Am I mistaken in my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope, the snippet below might resolve the issue.

```
String msg  = "Invalid password entered. You have {0,number,integer} {0,choice,   1#attempt|1<attempts} remaining.";
int attemptCount = 1; 
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(msg, attemptCount, attemptCount));
```

the result is,

Invalid password entered. You have 1 attempt remaining.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I hadn't tried this, but this put me on to the right track. turns out that message format doesn't parse it to a number if it's a string representation! Just had to change what I was passing to be an Object array